# Highcharts basic bar graphs. How to remove strokewith from the bars

Tags: highcharts, jsfiddle

While using a demo highchart (from highcharts.com). To be more specific a basic bar chart, a grey theme. 
As in this one http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic/gray

The bars on the graph in grey theme have a white line around them that I want to remove. I found in the javascript that it is strokewith=1 that make them appear. I can't find a way to set it to 0 since it is in the library from highcharts. How can i access strokewith=1 locally ?

best regards from Iceland :)

Answer (score 5):

This is handled with the [`borderWidth`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.borderWidth) property. I recommend checking out the documentation on the API. Set `borderWidth: 0` to get your result.